# UI block when I use a timer

Tags: c#, animation, grid

I try to move a grid in my window with an animation, but the animation doesn't happen, so I put a timer so that you can see the animation little by little but it still dont work :/

Here is my code:

```
class Animation
{
    private int x_dropGridToBottom;
    private Grid grid_dropGridToBottom;
    private System.Timers.Timer t;

    public Animation()
    {
        t = new System.Timers.Timer();
        t.Interval = 500;
    }

    private void TimerElapsed_DropGridToBottom(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        while (x_dropGridToBottom > 0)
        {
            x_dropGridToBottom--;

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                grid_dropGridToBottom.Margin = new Thickness(0, x_dropGridToBottom, 0, x_dropGridToBottom);
            });
        }
        if (x_dropGridToBottom == 0)
            t.Stop();
    }

    internal void DropGridToBottom(Grid grid, Window window)
    {
        grid.Margin = new Thickness(0, window.Height, 0, window.Height);

        // 0 x 0 x (x = window.height)
        // x = -y (y=412)
        // x (=) 0

        grid_dropGridToBottom = grid;
        x_dropGridToBottom = Convert.ToInt32(window.Height);

        t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed_DropGridToBottom);
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

And here is the code when I press the button that is supposed to start the animation :

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Animation anim = new Animation();
        anim.DropGridToBottom(grid_2, this);
    }
```

Somebody has an idea of why and how I can make my grid move little by little but not directly in one go (as it does nowadays).

Thank you

Comment: Your `TimerElapsed_DropGridToBottom` method has a while loop, which *does* drop it all the way to the bottom. Why do you have that loop, when the point of the timer is to call that method once every half second? Just remove the while loop and it may well do exactly what you want.

Comment: i'm stupid xD thank you :)